# TypeScript intersection involving optional fields widens type (rather than narrows)

Tags: typescript

So when I check for one type extending another type that involves optional fields, I get the expected behavior.

If I add an intersection to that check (which should further narrow the type), the type seems to get wider instead.

Why?

```
type THasOptionalNum = {
  A?: number;
};

type THasRequiredString = {
  B: string;
};

type ObjectWithOnlyRequiredString = {
  B: string;
};

type Example1 = ObjectWithOnlyRequiredString extends THasOptionalNum ? true : false; // false
type Example2 = ObjectWithOnlyRequiredString extends THasOptionalNum & THasRequiredString ? true : false; // true
```

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgEgQwM4HkzAJYHsB2CA2AcgK4C2UAvFAN4BQUUAggPwBcUOZARhAE4DctAL6DaoSLERIAShACOxDLwgATAMrBeGHAHNKNelABC7JJu07BI2mPDQUXAFYQAxsADqGYAAsUOfCCyCkqqGlq6+nQMJlBm4ZbCouLQAKIAHgikYPgQAIz6Ds5unj5+AUGKyurmERBpwBA4KkiSyGiYuAQk5MxQmsTQ7ABmBEgQ-FAA9JNQI-hjthLpmdkQAEwFTq4eXr7+gfKVoTV6dQ1NLfBt6Nh4RGRQAGStMoch1fFQvf2Ds6PjUxmPyAA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that the type gets wider, but rather that when optional properties are involved, Typescript's rules for assignability are somewhat counterintuitive:

1. The type `{B: string}` is assignable to `{B: string, A?: number}` because the `A` property is not required.
2. The type `{B: string, A?: number}` is assignable to the type `{A?: number}` because it has strictly more properties.
3. But the type `{B: string}` is *not* assignable to the type `{A?: number}` because they have no properties in common.

In practical terms, this makes sense ─ most of the time, if you tried to use `{B: string}` where `{A?: number}` is expected, it's a mistake and you would want the compiler to give you an error message about it. But from another perspective, this is highly unexpected, because it means that type assignability is not [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

For your specific examples, `Example1` is testing (3.) and `Example2` is testing (1.), hence the result.